# Why are some names briefly replaced by "… Groot" in the final credits?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, credits, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

In the ending credits of Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2, some names appear as *Baby Groot* or *I am Groot*<sup>(1)</sup> before being replaced by the person's name. What does this mean?

<sup>(1)</sup> I don't remember the exact text

Comment: It seems to be nothing but a joke in a credit sequence that is already full of other equally meaningless quirks.

Comment: The only explanation I can think to is that it marked people who had a baby while making the movie.

Comment: I think it means the producers are being playful with the audience, like the Zuker brothers used to do.

Comment: I wouldn't even have imagined *any* explanation. But I don't know.

Comment: I also thought to remember that those names actually read "I am Groot" rather than "Baby Groot" (which of course might also throw your explanation out the window). But maybe I just don't remember it well enough.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson You're right, it may have been "I am Groot", I don't remember exactly, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Similar joke credits were seen in the "[Spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(Monty_Python))" episode of *Monty Python's Flying Circus*: Spam Terry Jones, Michael Spam Palin, John Spam John Spam John Spam Cleese, Graham Spam Spam Spam Chapman, Eric Spam Egg and Chips Idle, Terry Spam Sausage Spam Egg Spam Gilliam, etc. I don't know if that was the first instance of joke credits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They all said, "I Am Groot". Because "I am Groot" means anything Groot wants it to mean. Including that person's name. This is the same as many movies or shows that have jokes in their credits. Like the Simpson's Little Tree House of Horror episodes where all the names are given funny horror themes or middle names.

Comment: As another example, there's a `Friends` episode where all the cast and crew have 'Arquette' added to their names, to honour the marriage of Courtney Cox to David Arquette.  Basically, it's a bit of fun

Comment: A further example, the Top Gear specials will usually do something funny with the names related to the special. So for the Arctic special they were all called "Sir Ranulph XXX", as an allusion to Sir Ranulph Fiennes, a famous British explorer.